# How to use data stored in *.testsettings for parallel testing on multiple machines

Tags: c#, unit-testing, parallel-processing, mstest, selenium-grid

I have some testMethods written in MStest c#. Now I would like to run them in parallel while each method or each group of methods run on remote machines and different browsers. I would like to do so by defining the combinations in a file and get the parameters in the code in parallel and run them, as doing so in TestNG in Java that enables get [@parameters ..]. thanks!! BTW, I'm implementing that with selenium grid.

Answer (score 0):

TestRunParameters and TestContext.Props could be and options for you:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/09/04/supplying-run-time-parameters-to-tests/

Comment: OK. but this option requires visual studio enterprise. does'nt it?

Comment: I do not think so
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.aspx